# Installing disqus comment on a jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll, blogs, disqus

I have followed the instruction on the Disqus page on *how to install disqus comment* but, it does not load up when I deploy my blog site.
I put the disqus universal code into the includes folder and then added it in the `post.html` file.
I changed the following code in the universal disqus code:

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = {{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = {{ page.url }}; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable 
};
```

In the `post.html` file I have:

```html
{% include comments.html %}
```

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = "{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}"; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = "{{ page.url }}"; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable 
};
```

I had to put the `this.page.url` into strings quotes as you can see from the code above. The same goes for the `this.page.identifier`